# Can ones frequency/propensity of utilizing American (either debit or) credit cards' chargeback mechanisms affect the chances of future times' success

Tags: united-states, england-and-wales, consumer-protection, payment, credit-report

If one requests many chargebacks, can this degrade one's credibility in the credit card issuers/payment networks' eyes, or reduce the chances of future chargeback disputes being adjudicated in a consumer's favor?

Can the different networks or the different issuing institutions share information between each other as with credit scores?

How does the situation differ between credit cards and debit cards chargebacks/disputes?

Interested in answers pertaining to either the USA or England and Wales.

Comment: Are you asking whether credit agencies actually consider such activity in their ratings, or are you asking whether the government has set up rules about doing so?

Comment: I believe that the ultimate charge back decision is made in a credit card processing system sponsored arbitration forum in the U.S. which means that it can ignore the relevant law, if any, and 'anything goes", so "yes", in theory it could. I'm not clear on the law in England andWales. But I would research before providing a definitive answer.

Comment: Well, you'd be right in that I would be more interested in whether it actually is factored in rather than whether the decision makers are legally permitted to factor it in. But isn't there federal US legislation that requires chargeback requests to be honoured for credit card transactions at least if not also debit card transactions under slightly different  terms for  various different types of scenarios like unauthorized charges but also things like unsatisfactory service?